# Python : How can I run a program at a certain time

Tags: python, time

I want to run a program at a certain time.

For example, When I run the program, it will be executed at 5 p.m

How can I implement the above function using Python?

Comment: This hasn't much to do with Python. The question is, how to run a certain program or command at a specific time. On unix-based operating systems you'd want to look into cron jobs.

Comment: While running program, how can I execute a certain code like print("This is time to wake up!) at a specific time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With**in** Python, thus within a long/permanent running (service) process of your own, you can use `sched.scheduler` or `threading.Timer` from the standard lib or use custom code (in a thread).

For **starting** a python script in a timed manner ordinarly **as a user** use OS means (crontab [*nix], Scheduled Tasks [Windows], ...) or use 3rd party scheduling apps - as you would do for scheduling other programs.
A python program could control those schedulers via API (e.g. `win32com.taskscheduler`) or command-line/`popen`...

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments this has nothing to do with python and rather with your OS.

So if you are on **Linux** run the command `crontab -e` and enter the lines:

```
* 9 * * 0-5 python /path/to/your/python/script
* 17 * * 6 python /path/to/your/python/script
```

The first line is for 9am every day except on saturday and the second one is for 17pm saturday.

If you are on **Windows** press the `windows button + R`, then type: `taskschd.msc` which opens the task scheduler. Here press "Action" and "Create task..." which opens a new windows which lets you create a new task, the instructions there is self explanatory.

Comment: `00 09 * * 0-5 python /path/to/your/python/script` is simpler for every day at 9am except saturday.

Comment: Changed to 0-5, the 00 before 09 is unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with python you could use [Celery beats](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), although not recommended if you're not using celery.

On *nix systems you just want to use [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) instead and on windows use the [task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).